# Linking glade file with program g++

Tags: c++, g++, gtk3, glade

Glade files and the program files can get a bit messy, this becomes a problem when you want your program to be portable. Is there any way to bind your program with your glade files?

Source code (unfinished but working project): https://github.com/caelwithcats/valuator

Comment: compile commands in source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Gio Resources to include the contents of your `.glade` files in the application, and then use GtkBuilder's `add_from_resource()` to load them: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-gio-resource.html.en